# R iconv() error - unsupported conversion from 'latin1' to 'ASCII'

Tags: r, iconv

I tried the following code in R

```
iconv("123", "latin1", "ASCII")
```

and get the following error:

> Unsupported conversion from 'latin1' to 'ASCII'.

If I try to convert from "UTF-8" to "ASCII" then it is fine.

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: What OS are you on? You may need to check `iconvlist` for the proper encoding on your platform.  It's described in `?iconv`

Comment: `grep("LATIN",iconvlist(), value=TRUE)`
 [1] "CSISOLATIN1"        "CSISOLATIN2"        "CSISOLATIN3"       
 [4] "CSISOLATIN4"        "CSISOLATIN5"        "CSISOLATIN6"       
 [7] "CSISOLATINARABIC"   "CSISOLATINCYRILLIC" "CSISOLATINGREEK"   
[10] "CSISOLATINHEBREW"   "CSPC862LATINHEBREW" "LATIN-9"           
[13] "LATIN1"             "LATIN10"            "LATIN2"            
[16] "LATIN3"             "LATIN4"             "LATIN5"            
[19] "LATIN6"             "LATIN7"             "LATIN8"            
[22] "RISCOS-LATIN1" .. and `grep("latin",iconvlist(), value=TRUE)
character(0)`